# How to create a animation for my tableviewcell images alone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have created expanded tableview using plist, I have populated all the values and images into my tableview. Here I want to make animation for my particular cell when user click that cell.

For example, first time images will be default, next time if I click that cell, the particular cell get expanded. Here I need to make my image has hide; again if user press it will show the image. How to do this?

Comment: you mean you want to toggle the display of image view ?

Comment: Yes..toggle along with blinking animation

Answer (score 1):

Every time the user taps a cell, a `UITableViewDelegate` method gets called, and in this method you can reload the cell:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

When a cell is reloaded, the method below is called (between the others), and the only thing you have to do is to return a different height according with the current state of the cell:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return (/* cell state */) ? 100.0 : 50.0;
}
```

You have multiple ways to store your cell's state, you can do it in its model for example.

There are other ways also, this is only a solution. But the key point is that you have to reload the cell, and return a different height according with the conditions you want to consider.

Answer (score 0):

You can check my full solution in the following [github](https://github.com/texas16/ExpandableTableView)

Here is some of my implementation.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    movies = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
              (NSArray*)[[Section alloc ] init:@"Istanbul" movieNames:@[@"Uskudar", @"Sariyer"] isExpanded:false],
              (NSArray*)[[Section alloc ] init:@"Bursa" movieNames:@[@"Osmangazi", @"Mudanya", @"Nilufer"]
               isExpanded:false],
              (NSArray*)[[Section alloc ] init:@"Antalya" movieNames:@[@"Alanya", @"Kas"] isExpanded:false], nil
              ];             
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return movies.count;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return ((Section*)movies[section]).movies.count ;
}

-(void)toggleSection:(ExpandableHeaderFoorterView *)headerView withSection:(int)section
{
    ((Section*)movies[section]).expanded = !((Section*)movies[section]).expanded;
    [expandableTableView beginUpdates];
    for (int i= 0; i< ((Section*)movies[section]).movies.count; i++)
    {
        NSArray* rowsToReload = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:section], nil];
        [expandableTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToReload
 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }

    [expandableTableView endUpdates];

}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    ExpandableHeaderFoorterView* headerView = [[ExpandableHeaderFoorterView alloc] initWithCustom:((Section*)movies[section]).genre withSection:(int)section withDelegate:self];
    return (ExpandableHeaderFoorterView*)headerView;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

http://www.iostute.com/2015/04/expandable-and-collapsable-tableview.html

You can see this tutorial. It's a very good tutorial based on expandable tableview cell.

Comment: This is probably very helpful, but link-only answers are discouraged here, since they break often. They are fine to offer, but perhaps as an addendum to an answer in its own right.